# How to call controller action dynamically from HTTPHandler?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httphandler, ashx

In my MVC Web application, I have created two controllers. One for handling requests coming from Mobile devices and other for handling desktop browsers.

I am trying to call the appropriate controller's action depending on who is calling the application. This check will be done by a custom logic which is ready with me.

What will be the best approach to achive this dynamic redirection to controller? My approach is to use one HTTPHandler (ashx), in which I will check the source and then give a call to appropriate controller. The device/browser will hit the URL pointing to this ashx file.

I tried somehting like this..... in ProcessRequest() method of my handler.

```
 <source checking logic>
 ...
 ...
 var webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(MyFinalURL);
 var response = webRequest.GetResponse();
 context.Response.Write(response);
```

Will this be the best approach? or is there any better alternative? Will HTTPModule also work for this prupose? Please suggest.

Also how will I redirect to controller action from ashx file?

Comment: Can you please post some code ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Scott Hanselman's blog post on mobile capable view engine](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek10NewMobileViewEnginesForASPNETMVC3SpeccompatibleWithASPNETMVC4.aspx)